# Walk two lists (no zip)

Tags: python

This is my implementation:

```
def walk_two(a, b):
    for x in a:
        for y in b:
            yield x, y

a = xrange(2)
b = xrange(3)

for x, y in walk_two(a, b):
    print x, y
```

With this output:

```
0 0
0 1
0 2
1 0
1 1
1 2
```

Is there a better (more pythonic) way of doing that? A built-in? A more generic walkN?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking for `itertools.product`:

```
from itertools import product
a = xrange(2)
b = xrange(3)

for x, y in product(a, b):
    print x, y
```

Answer (score 3):

itertools.product does what you want and is extensible to more lists:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product

```
import itertools
a = xrange(2)
b = xrange(3)

for x, y in itertools.product(a, b):
    print x, y
```

Output:

```
0 0
0 1
0 2
1 0
1 1
1 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).

Comment: This is a link-only answer, which are strogly discouraged. Please add at least an example.

Comment: At least, we all agree ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think this one is slightly better:

```
>>> for a in xrange(2):
...   for b in xrange(3):
...     print a, b
... 
0 0
0 1
0 2
1 0
1 1
1 2
```

You don't need to use the generator here, as you are using the xrange() function. The function returns xrange object instead of a list.

```
>>> a = xrange(10)
>>> a
xrange(10)
>>>
```

Comment: Not the more pythonic but this code is the fastest one.

Comment: In my case, performance is not a worry, readability is. Having a single loop instead of two, improves readability drastically. Having a single loop instead of N (for the general case), makes wonders for readability.

Comment: @jeckyll2hide, this answer was being downvoted. Yeah, it's awful to nest many *for loops*, but if someone stumbles into this question with only two lists to iterate and performance is a worry... use this solution! No need to downvote.

Comment: @xbello: I didn't downvote, but I should have. The answer here is the same as the code in my question.

Comment: The answer here is not exactly the same as in your question. You didn't need to use the walk_two method. Is it unnecessary here.